# ¿Actualizar registro django en corto periodo de tiempo(ms)?

Tags: python, django, api, rest

Saludos espero me puedan ayudar con este tema de verdad se los agradecería!

La situación es la siguente:

En mi proyecto `django` tengo un endpoint en el cual el cliente se conecta hace una solicitud para actualizar un registro en la db. El endpoint toma los datos de la solicitud y hace varias comprobaciones de seguridad; si todo va bien se procede a actualizar el registro, de lo contrario retorna un error.

Hasta allí todo bien, el endpoint funciona correctamente, el detalle se presenta cuando el cliente envia 5 o mas solicitudes casi al mismo tiempo (diferencias de ms) para actualizar el mismo registro, al servidor no le da tiempo de procesar todas las solicitudes y de las 5 solo actualiza 3. Las otras 2 solicitudes retornan un resultado incorrecto.

Ya he optimizado las query lo mas que pude por lo cual creo que ese no es el problema, el servidor se tarda en promedio 0.1 ms en procesar cada solicitud!

Espero me puedan brindar algún consejo o solución para este tema. Gracias!

Edit:
Las 5(o mas) solicitudes no generan ningun tipo de error al procesarlas pero retornan resultados incorrectos.

tratare de ilustrar con un ejemplo para que se entienda un poco mejor:
supongamos que tengo una tabla en la db llamada Dulces, esta tiene un campo int llamdo Cantidad con la catidad total de dulces disponibles, el cliente llama al endpoint para actualizar la cantidad de dulces disponibles, pasando como agurmento la cantidad a sumar al valor del campo Cantidad de la base de datos, hasta alli ningun problema la solicitud se procesa correctamente.

cuando el cliente hace muchas llamadas simultaneas en un corto periodo de tiempo(0.05 ms), las primeras solicitudes se procesan bien y se actualiza correctamente la cantidad de dulces, pero llega un momento en que las solicitudes toman un valor Cantidad antiguo porque el servidor supongo que esta a mitad de procesar otra solicitud, y eso genera que retorne valores incorrectos.

Espero haberme dando a entender. Gracias!

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error reportado? ¿Has mirado los logs de la aplicación? Podrías editar tu pregunta y agregar dicha información. Gracias!

Comment: ¿Que base de datos estas utilizando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes varias opciones:

- Aumenta la capacidad de tu servidor para que pueda resolver todas las solicitudes en el menor tiempo posible. Lo puedes hacer verticalmente, aumenta la memoria y procesadores u horizontalmente, aumentando más máquinas y balanceando la carga
- Optimiza tu código. Verificando los índices o el código SQL que crea Django. Hay varias herramientas que te ayuda a eso, como la `django-debug-toolbar`.
- Acepta todas las solicitudes, pero **no intentes procesarlas inmediatamente**, colócalas en una fila, primero en entrar primero en salir. A los usuarios les puedes regresar una *promesa* de procesamiento. El concepto asi se llama, *promises*.
- Reduce la velocidad en la que un usuario puede hacer solicitudes, limita el número de solicitudes por minuto para que sea equivalente con la capacidad de tu servidor. El concepto se llama *throttling*.

Por cierto, ¿ya leíste esta guía: [***"Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable"***](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Si no lo has leído, te recomiendo que lo hagas, te va a servir de mucho.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu repuesta, la solucion fue crear un script tomando como base tu 3er punto(fila), con eso problema solucionado!